# What is the correct (stable, efficient) way to use matrix inversion in numpy?

Tags: matlab, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

In Matlab, using the inv() function is often discouraged due to numerical instability (see description section in http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html).
It is suggested to replace an expression like:

```
inv(A)*B
```

(where both A and B are matrices), with:

```
A\B
```

This becomes critical when the inverted matrix A is close to singular.

Is there a nice way to write this in numpy / scipy? (would solve() work?)

Comment: See this Stackoverflow question - [Left inverse in numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250403/left-inverse-in-numpy-or-scipy)

Comment: `linalg.solve()` is the correct way to do this - see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve . I believe it's numerically more stable than the inverse (using LU decomposition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use the left inverse.

This is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250403/left-inverse-in-numpy-or-scipy).

To summarize (imitatio, aemulatio):

- Use [`linalg.lstsq(A,y)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) in general.
- You can use [`linalg.solve(A,y)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve) if you know `A` meets the right conditions.